# How to connect and test a Windows CE project on a real device?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-ce, motorola, activesync

***Note*** : I'm using VS2008 and I'm working on windows 7.

I'm developping a Windows CE application which will run on a Motorola MC3000 device with a WinCE 5.0 like OS .

I tried to use ActiveSync in order to make the test with the selected device possible but it doesn't work on win7, so I tried to find another tool and I found Windows Mobile Device Center based on [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/8e08e112-1cee-4436-b2d3-00c87e33b71f/) .

So Now I can browse with the device but unfortunately I can not test with it : The device have a "santech" application installed and can not kill the app. (even when I reboot the machine, the autorun lunch the app. automatically). Also when I try to deploy my application on the device it return error reports ; sometimes "no disc space" sometimes "the .exe can not be found".

I'm really stucked.

Can some one help me with this, I will be really gratefull.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the debugger is attaching just fine, it's just unable to either fully copy the app and dependencies, or there's not enough memory to execute it.

If you can browse the device, you can stop the "santech" app from running.  You just have to determine what is launching it.  It might be a shortcut in the `\Windows\Startup` folder.  It might be through a registry entry at [`\[HKLM\Init\]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms924527.aspx).  IIRC, Symbol devices also support a `*.run` file in the `\Application\Startup` folder, so check that as well.

One of those is launching the app, so you can eliminate that if you desire.

Next, check the available memory on the device by looking in the Control Panel under `System->Memory` and adjusting the slider to provide more storage space.  If there's not enough Storage Memory to store your app, you might try changing the deployment directory (under Project Properties->Device) to push the app binaries to non-volatile storage of some sort (on-board Flash, SD card, etc), if the device has it.

If you don't have enough Program Memory to run your app, you might be out of luck.  Try killing processes to free up some space and playing with the memory allocation slider.

Comment: Hi Really thx for your answer :)

but I don't know how to configure what is launching  !! :(

Comment: Again, it depends on how it is launching.  It might be a shortcut in Startp.  If so, remove that.  It might be a registry entry (pointed to above).  If so, remove that.  It might be a run file.  If so, remove that.

Comment: ok, the device is using Motorola AppLuncher and the problem is that I can not kill the app. even remove the appLuncher startup from windows file !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can debug from inside VS2008 as well. You'll need to tell it to connect to a device as it automatically sends it to a emulator. To do that you need to select `Windows CE Device` from the dropdown list found in the "Devices" toolbar (To enable go to View, Toolbars and select Devices). Then hit F5 and it should start up on your device. You might get a couple of pop-up boxes that contain a list of devices; make sure these are set to `Windows CE Device` as well.

[This handy page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513828%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) should provide the information you need also.